# Query boolean and if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have table name report the detail like this

```
No(autoincrement)       Code       Stats(bool)
--------------------------------------
       1                 F01        0
       2                 F02        0
       3                 F03        0
       4                 F03        1
       5                 F03        1
       6                 F04        1
       7                 F04        0
```

so the scenario is if code have value for stats is true then show them all and if the code didnt have value true then only show the false so the result i want is  (note : one code always have 1 record for value false)

```
No(autoincrement)           Code       Stats
--------------------------------------------
           1                  F01        0
           2                  F02        0
           4                  F03        1
           5                  F03        1
           6                  F04        1
```

because f01 and f02 didnt have value stats true then show them and for case f03 and f04 because have value true for stat show them all true and ignore the false value

so how the query for i get the result

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Comment: Im using mysql for my dbms

Comment: Check My Solution using MySql DenseRank @InheavenA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want `DENSE_RANK()` function

```
select * from
(
    select *,
            dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by Stats desc) Seq
    from table t
) t
where Seq = 1
```

If, you don't want to go with `subquery` form, you could explore the above things via *TOP with ties* which available in SQL Server

```
select top 1 with ties [No(autoincrement)], Code, [Stats(bool)]
from table t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by [Stats(bool)] desc)
```

Since `MySQL` doesn't have analytical function. So, you could explore these thing via  `UNION ALL`

```
select * 
from table t
where exists (
    select 1 from table
    where autoincrement  = t.autoincrement  and Stats = 1
) UNION ALL 
select * 
from table t
where not exists (
    select 1 from table
    where code = t.code and Stats = 1) 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: how to use dense_rank if im using mysql for query

Comment: What is 1 from select 1 is ?

Comment: @InheavenA.. `select 1` means return 1 for every matched record that satisfied the filtered criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT No,Code,Stats FROM
(SELECT No,Code,Stats,
  Case when @Code = t.Code Then
            Case when @stats != t.stats  Then
                 @DenseRank := @DenseRank + 1
            ELSE
                 @DenseRank := 1
            END
   Else
      @DenseRank := 1 
   END as DenseRank,
  @Code :=t.code as VarCode,
  @stats :=t.stats as varstatus
  FROM Table1 t join
  (Select @DenseRank := 1,@Code := '',@stats := '' )r
Order BY CODE,Stats DESC)
AS T1
WHERE
DenseRank=1
Order BY CODE,Stats DESC;
```

Output

```
No  Code    Stats
1   F01     0
2   F02     0
4   F03     1
5   F03     1
6   F04     1
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f868a/3